# img на всю высоту блока

Tags: html, css

Есть такая разметка, родительский элемент резиновый.
Вопрос: как растянуть картинку на всю высоту, сохранить пропорции, разместить строго по центру и спрятать части, которые вылезут слева и справа.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* desired width */
  border: 2px solid #d6a86a;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper-news {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper-news">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yUbR.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Приложу картинку для наглядного понимания:
[image]

- черный - блок;
- красный - изображение;
- желтый - видимая часть изображения;

Comment: `.wrapper-news{height: 100%} img{width: auto; height: 100%;}` что бы было пропорционально

Comment: А по центру выровнять картинку?

Comment: А чтоб скрыто края - родительскому элементу overflow: hidden; а изображению отрицательные margin там , где нужно чтоб не выдавило

Comment: https://www.google.am/search?q=css+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83&oq=css+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8587j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Интересно зачем такие вопросы здесь задавать и ждать часами ответа? если есть `google`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* desired width */
  border: 2px solid #d6a86a;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper-news {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper-news img {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper-news">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yUbR.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а это свойство центрирует transform: translateX(-50%);

Comment: вот пример - все работает - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/goaymzgh/

Comment: Ох извините, я не прав.